# Finding if binary representation is palindrome in java

Tags: java

he want to know if the number is wonderful

A number is wonderful if this number is odd and its binary representation is palindrome.

**This is my problem** https://codeforces.com/group/MWSDmqGsZm/contest/223205/problem/C

> the error is :
> Runtime error on test 4

```
static public void zero(long n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println("NO");
    }
}

static public String binary(long n) {

    String bin = "";
    while (n > 0) {
        bin += (n % 2 + 0);
        n /= 2;
    }

    return bin;
}

static public void CheckOdd(long n) {

    if (n % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.println("YES");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    long n = in.nextLong();
    if (n == 0) {
        zero(n);
    } else {

        long x = Integer.parseInt(binary(n));

        long original = x;
        long remainder, reverse = 0;
        while (x != 0) {
            remainder = x % 10;
            reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
            x /= 10;
        }

        if (original == reverse) {
            CheckOdd(n);
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }
    }
}
```

input : 262145

```
output :   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1000000000000000001" at 
    java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
        at NewTest.main(NewTest.java:39)
```

Comment: You don’t need to convert to long to check if a number is odd. Think about it, what part of a number determines if it is odd or even?

Comment: You use `Integer.parseInt` to parse your binary string into an Integer without regard for the base it's in. The decimal number `1000000000000000001` is greater than the greatest number an Integer can store, hence the error. You could probably fix it by using Long.parseLong instead, but your code could be simplified a great deal as mentionned above

Comment: Are you not allowed to use `Integer.toBinaryString` and `StringBuilder.reverse`?

Comment: This could easily be done using some bit magic. E.g. something like this: https://ideone.com/0wZ3Y6